# Products dropdown from same category inside Woocommerce product short description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown, product, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, I would like to add a drop down in product short description that shows all products that have the same category(ies). It will be even better if it was possible to go to the product page of the selected product.

I didn't see any threads that fulfill what I am trying to do.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2021 Update** - Added `product_id` as argument, allowing the shortcode to be used for a defined product ID (for example on a page).

The following will make a custom shortcode that you can use in your product short description (or even in the product description) and will display a dropdown from same product category than the current product.

The code:

```
add_shortcode( 'products_dropdown', 'wc_products_from_cat_dropdown' );
function wc_products_from_cat_dropdown( $atts ) {
        // Shortcode Attributes
        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'product_id' => '', 
        ), $atts, 'products_dropdown' );
        
    $product_id = is_product() ? get_the_id() : $atts['product_id'];
    
    if ( empty($product_id) )
        return;

    ob_start();

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'post__not_in'     => array( $product_id ),
        'tax_query' => array( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ) ,
        ) ),
    ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

    echo '<div class="products-dropdown"><select name="products-select" id="products-select">
    <option value="">'.__('Choose a related product').'</option>';

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    echo '<option value="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</option>';

    endwhile;

    echo '</select> <button type="button" style="padding:2px 10px; margin-left:10px;">'._("Go").'</button></div>';

    wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;

    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            var a = '.products-dropdown', b = a+' button', c = a+' select', s = '';
            $(c).change(function(){
                s = $(this).val();
                console.log(s); // just for testing (to be removed)
            });
             $(b).click(function(){
                if( s != '' ) location.href = s;
            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE**

1). For single product pages: Just paste the following shortcode in the product short description (or descrition):

```
[products_dropdown]
```

2). For single product pages, inside php code:

```
echo do_shortcode("[products_dropdown]");
```

3). on any post or page within the text editor, define the product_id argument *(below the defined product id is **`37`**)*:

```
[products_dropdown product_id="37"]
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you look at my other issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829990/remove-product-image-in-the-products-widget

Comment: @glennkline You should clarify a bit, may be adding more details and a screen shot…

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec Thanks for the solution. Is there a way the dropdown list can be sorted alphabetically? Thanks.

Comment: @HamzaAhmad Add to the `WP_Query` arguments array this line: `orderby => 'name',`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme's 'functions.php' which will display all products of your current product's category.

```
function add_products_short_description() {
    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
    if ( $product_cats ) {
        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats );

        $product_args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'product_cat' => $single_cat->name );
        $products = new WP_Query( $product_args );
        if ( $products->have_posts() ) :  echo '<ul>';
            while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); global $product; 
                echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $products->ID ).'">'.get_the_title($products->ID).'</a></li>';
            endwhile;
            echo '</ul>';
        endif;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_products_short_description', 15 );
```

Comment: Its not working.. I added the Code to my Theme Functions Functions.php at the bottom.

Here is my link.

http://planroom.shetlerprinting.com/product/moffit-gregg-residence-complete-plan-set/

Comment: Did you removed 'short description hook' from your WooCommerce template?

Comment: I dont think so. I can add descriptions and they show up. Help?

Comment: Can you add short description and check whether it's displaying?