# Displaying Woocommerce products dropdown from same category in a page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to list all the products within the same category in a dropdown on a Wordpress page.

I tried using *[Products dropdown from same category inside Woocommerce product short description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823551/products-dropdown-from-same-category-inside-woocommerce-product-short-descriptio/51825426#51825426)* answer code. however, it only works within the product short description or product description. It is displaying nothing when I put the shortcode `[products_dropdown]` in a page.

Is there a way I can use the shortcode `[products_dropdown]` in a page?

Comment: Where exactly you want to put/display this code in page???

Comment: It says in the beginning `if( ! is_product() ) return;`. `is_product`
 =  Returns true when viewing a single product. So the 'page' whatever this may be? (as indicated by @TanmayPatel) 
most likely does not meet that condition

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I wanted to use the shortcode in the text editor on the page. Is that possible?

Comment: @HamzaAhmad Sorry Just [updated again once more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51825426/3730754), there was another mistake:) … I am testing actually. Now it works on post and pages, for a defined product ID.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, it's displaying perfectly now! Really appreciate your help :)